# Fabric won't show my Firebase application

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm desperately trying to configure Crashlytics into my Firebase iOS app but I can't get it to work. My app had Crashlytics configured before it was integrated with Firebase, so I tried removing the app from Fabric and redo the configuration from scratch. Right now, I managed to add the app again to Fabric. Then I went to Crashlytics in Firebase, selected my iOS app (I also have an Android app that's already configured with Crashlytics), selected "Crashlytics is already installed", then clicked the "Link the application in Fabric" button, which redirects me to Fabric. Then I signed in to Google (which weirdly works in Firefox but not in Chrome), then clicked "Start linking", and on the right, I see plenty of Firebase application configured in my account, but not the one I'm interested in right now. I don't know if this is linked, but for both the Android app and the iOS app in this Firebase project, Firebase doesn't seem to be able to complete its SDK configuration. It is stuck forever on "verifying installation".

Comment: You should integrate Crashlytics of firebase, because Firebase Crashlytics and Fabric are merged.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm trying to do. I'm following all the instructions to do just that. But it doesn't work!

Comment: I would like to suggest don't follow any instruction on Fabric documentation, just follow Firebase Crashlytics, everything will work fine.

Comment: @SagarChauhan It did not. Which is why I resorted to reconfiguring my app in Fabric.

Comment: Could you please show which Run Script have you added in build phase ?

Comment: Right now, my run script looks like this: "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" 94dc2d5a1403xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbcba4cc53e45 9b70c6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc1ef7175b337330132c8db7f06266b3d548d09c0d0

Comment: Thanks are you an owner on the Firebase project in question?

Comment: @ToddBurner Yes I am